# Getting SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommand confused

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I've got this calling method:

```
public string RunReportSteps(int _reportKey) {
    DataTable fStepsTable;
    fStepsTable =  GetStepsTable("xxx.console.pr_xxx");
    return (string)fStepsTable.Rows[1][3];
}
```

It calls this private method:

```
private DataTable GetStepsTable(string procName) {
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter())
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, conn)) {

        conn.Open();

        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@ReportKey", this.ReportKey);
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;

        DataSet mySet = new DataSet();
        adapt.Fill(mySet);     //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<errors here
        return mySet.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the following error message?

> Procedure or function 'pr_xxx' expects parameter
>   '@ReportKey', which was not supplied.

Comment: I don't know if it's the root of the issue, but shouldn't you specify that you are using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that `procName` is the name of the stored-procedure. You haven't set the [`CommandType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx) of the SqlCommand to `StoredProcedure`:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, conn))
using(var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // <<< this was missing

    SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@ReportKey", this.ReportKey);
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(table);     
    return table;
}
```

Comment: thanks ...+ I had no real need for the dataset; + I'd confused the order of the adapter and sqlcommand!

Comment: @whytheq: note also that you don't need to open the connection manually since the `DataAdapter` will do it for you in [`Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx).