# SQL Exception was unhandled, : Incorrect syntax near 'User'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have looked on the forum and tried everything people have suggested and I cannot find a solution that will make this solution work. The program will run until it has to connect to the database. Then at that point it will bring up the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'user'.

The `User` being the username in my login page.

Here is the code I have. Can anyone see any problems I'm missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LoginForm
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=        (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Username\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect      Timeout=30");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Username'"     +textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='"+textBox2.Text+"'",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            Main ss = new Main();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please check Username and Password and try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's your problem: `where Username'"   ` = missing an equals sign:  `where Username='"   `

Comment: And _please_ learn to use parameters instead of concatenating SQL - ESPECIALLY when accessing user/password information.

Comment: I can see the syntax error (missing equals sign).  When you've fixed it, try logging in as "dan'; DELETE FROM Login; -- ", then google for SQL injection.

Comment: Checked the forum? EVER considered stuff like learning the basics of debugging?

Comment: Also, *please* don't store passwords in plain text. Hashing and salting is good practice, even in local systems.

Answer (score 1):

Better use real `SqlParameter`. But first this should help:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Username ='"     +textBox1.Text + "' and Password ='"+textBox2.Text+"'",con);
```

But you program is very unsafe, because you can get [sql-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problems.

Look at this for SqlAdapter and SqlParameter: [Getting SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommand confused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13567570/2630261)

Answer (score 0):

One like stated by others this code is subject sql-injection

You don't need a datatable to get one value

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Spyer\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText =  "Select Count(*) From Login where Username = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and Password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
con.Open();
Int32 ccount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
con.Close();
```

this is a proper approach

```
String connString = @"Data Source (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Spyer\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
String sql = "Select Count(*) From Login where Username = @Name and Password = @Password";
Int32 ccount;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = textBox2.Text;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        ccount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```